# #1054 - Unknown column 'Pieter-Bracke' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having an issue with the following code when I try to import my database into PHPMyAdmin I get following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'Pieter-Bracke' in 'field list'... I don't really see what I am doing wrong here tbh.

```php
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `naam` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `leeftijd` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `occupatie` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `naam`, `leeftijd`, `occupatie`, `username`, `password`, `level`) VALUES
(1, `Pieter-Bracke`, `28`, 'Freelance webdeveloper', `Pieter`, `Pieter`, 0);
```

Comment: So, instead of (1, `Pieter-Bracke`, `28`, 'Freelance webdeveloper', `Pieter`, `Pieter`, 0) it should be (1, 'Pieter-Bracke', '28', 'Freelance webdeveloper', 'Pieter', 'Pieter', 0)

Comment: `data type` is not match with `insert query`

Comment: Ok, got it thx alot

Comment: Use this :- 

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `naam`, `leeftijd`, `occupatie`, `username`, `password`, `level`) VALUES
(1, 'Pieter-Bracke', '28', 'Freelance webdeveloper', 'Pieter', 'Pieter', 0);